# can we can add ready html code in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net

I was wondering if there is a way to convert and HTML template to ASP.NET? I am trying to convert a website template that was written in HTML that contains Javascript and CSS files to ASP.NET so I can connect to a SQL Server database.

I have limited coding experience with ASP.NET so any help is appreciated!

I also have access to an ASP template but it is not ASP.net unfortunately.

Comment: start reading asp.net or mvc..
and then ask some specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use regular html in an ASP.NET app.

Here, how to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 app:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Learn a bit then ask a specific question as was commented.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC **is** ASP.NET.